# QQline command works only on the last plot

Tags: r, plot

The formula below applies lm to a list 'dsets' that contains multiple datasets and stores the output in object 'models'.

```
models<-lapply(dsets,function(data){
lm(reformulate(termlabels=".",response=names(data)[1]),data)
})
```

I created this function to plot qqplot for each of the model outputs stored in object 'models' but it won't work

```
rstest<-function(x){
for (i in 1:length(x))
qqnorm(residuals(x[[i]]))
qqline(residuals(x[[i]]))
}
rstest(models)
```

I get the plots, but qqline works only on the last plot not all of the plots being generated. What am I missing in my function thats not making qqline iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first expression after `for(...)` is looped. Wrap the body of the `for` loop in `{}` to combine the two expressions.

```
rstest <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    qqnorm(residuals(x[[i]]))
    qqline(residuals(x[[i]]))
  }
}
rstest(models)
```

Using an editor/IDE that indents your code would have helped you to recognize this yourself.

Comment: thanks Roland - what editor would you recommend using? I'm using the default in Rstudio

Comment: RStudio indents your code by default. There is also an item in the "Code" menu for reindenting your code.